# Atualização Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Atualmente estou com a versão v8.10.0 e queria atualizá-lo para a 10.16, porém ao usar o: sudo npm cache clean -f recebo a seguinte resposta: using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing. Como resolver isso?

Comment: Essa mensagem é só um `warning`. Não faz diferença.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve desinstalar completamente o nodejs. Para isso veja este link a baixo:
Como deinstalar nodejs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426601/completly-uninstall-nodejs-npm-and-node-in-ubuntu-14-04

Então você poderá usar o nodejs através do `nvm` (Node Version Manage):
Instalação: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm 
**Note:** Se você estiver usando distribuição Debian, faça o seguintinte:
`sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev`

Feito isso é só instalar o `nvm`:
`wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash`
Ou acesso o seguinte link para mais detalhes https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm.

Após instalar execute os seguintes comandos:

```bsh
genesis@mrgenesis:~/$ nvm --version
0.34.0
genesis@mrgenesis:~/$ nvm ls-remote --lts | grep v10
       v10.13.0   (LTS: Dubnium)
       v10.14.0   (LTS: Dubnium)
       v10.14.1   (LTS: Dubnium)
       v10.14.2   (LTS: Dubnium)
       v10.15.0   (LTS: Dubnium)
       v10.15.1   (LTS: Dubnium)
       v10.15.2   (LTS: Dubnium)
->     v10.15.3   (LTS: Dubnium)
       v10.16.0   (Latest LTS: Dubnium)
```

Depois você poderá instalar a versão que quiser da seguinte forma:
`nvm install v10.16.0`

O `npm` será instalado automaticamente.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. Consegui fazer tudo certo aqui. Vlw